# getting error while installing psycopg2 in vscode on windows

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows

I am trying `pip install psycopg2` in vscode cmd on windows 8.1, which results in the following error.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\rock\envs\demo\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rock\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fczxt3cu\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rock\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fczxt3cu\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\rock\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-i_fkxw14' --python-tag cp38
       cwd: C:\Users\rock\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fczxt3cu\psycopg2\
  Complete output (22 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\sql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\_ipaddress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\_lru_cache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\psycopg2
  running build_ext
  building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pls. refer to the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section on how to ask questions here.

Your error message clearly states your system is missing a build dependency. Employ a search engine of your choice to learn how to provide that dependency, or how to circumvent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in the error message. You need the Visual C++ runtime installed. Go to

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

and download the version appropriate to your system, then install and try again.

### EDIT: Correct answer

The error message is misleading in this case. It's an issue with psycopg, it doesn't appear to support Python 3.8 on Windows yet. Solution is to use 3.7 until psycopg is ready.

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/990

Comment: Did you install 32bit or 64bit? Which is your Python install?

Comment: installed 64-bit. I am using python version 3.8.0

Comment: And it's a 64 bit Python install too?

Comment: Could be possible it's an issue with the psycopg distribution for Python 3.8 as this is a very new release. There is an issue on the Github page which is a little similar to yours https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/990 Maybe try with Python 3.7

Comment: you were right. I switched to python 3.7 and now it is installed and working fine. Thanx a lot for the help.